# Swift SCNNode 3D cube rotate to a point on cube

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Problem : Trying to rotate a cube to a point on the cube itself. That point is randomly created and it should appear in the centre of the screen.

Tried with lookAtConstraint and in `func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval)`  assigned the random point. But did not work (commented)

```
 cube = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeometry)
        cube.position = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        gamescn.rootNode.addChildNode(cube)

        cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 40)
        gamescn.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        lookAtConstraint

//        lookAtConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: cube)
//        lookAtConstraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true
//        cameraNode.constraints = [lookAtConstraint]
```

Also tried to get the deviation first centre point (initally [0,0,distance from center]) - then `cube.eulerAngles = deviation` in the `func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval)`. But cube rotates randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a simple solution with 3D geometry. There may be other elegant solutions out there.
Here is how I achieved that -

Made two utility function to get the asin & acos componet of angle between two points -

```
func angleBetweenVectorsCos(_ vectorB:SCNVector3) -> SCNFloat {
        let cosineAngle = (dot(vector: vectorB) / (magnitude * vectorB.magnitude))
        return SCNFloat(acos(cosineAngle))
}

func angleBetweenVectorsSin(_ vectorB:SCNVector3) -> SCNFloat {
        let cosineAngle = angleBetweenVectorsCos(vectorB)
        let sinangle = sqrt(1-cosineAngle*cosineAngle)
        return SCNFloat(acos(sinangle))
 }
```

Then - in `func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval)`  function I assigned angles calculated

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        if time > rotationTimer{


            let angleCos = lastposition.angleBetweenVectorsCos(movingTarget.position)
            let angleSin = lastposition.angleBetweenVectorsSin(movingTarget.position)
            SCNTransaction.begin()
            SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 0.5
            xDegree += angleSin
            yDegree += angleCos
            zDegree += 0

            if vMove {
                cube.eulerAngles.x =  xDegree
            }
            if hMove {
                cube.eulerAngles.y =  -yDegree
            }


            SCNTransaction.commit()
            lastposition = movingTarget.position
            .......    
            rotationTimer = time + 0.2
        }

    }
```

How to get the vMove(vertical movement) and hMove(horizontal movement) - just calculated in which surface the move object is by detecting the distance from origin.

I made a full github repo for this same. [See this and suggest some improvements](https://github.com/debs25/3DCubeRotateToFaceCamera)